Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationPolicyProvider.get_AllowsCachingPolicies()'.'
I created an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project.
But when I run the project, I get this error:

System.MissingMethodException : 'Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationPolicyProvider.get_AllowsCachingPolicies()'.'

The error happens on app.Run();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I don't understand it. I installed the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization but I still have the same problem.
Does anyone know what the problem is?


System.MissingMethodException : 'Method not found: 'Boolean
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationPolicyProvider.get_AllowsCachingPolicies()'.'

Can't reproduce the problem on my side.
I suggest you can try to re-create an API application using the ASP.NET Core Web API template, and in the Additional Information panel, set the Authentication type to None.

Then, running the application and check whether it works well or not? If still show the same error, please check your Visual Studio version and try to upgrade it to the latest version.
I'm using the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.12.3 and the new application works well (using the same code as yours in the program.cs file) and there is no need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization package specially.
Generally, for API application, we will use JWT authentication. To configure the API application to use JWT authentication, you can refer to the following steps:

Create API application using the ASP.NET Core Web API template.

Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package.

Add valid audience, valid issuer and secret key for JWT authentication in appsetting.cs file:
 {
   "Jwt": {
     "Key": "Yh2k7QSu4l8CZg5p6X3Pna9L0Miy4D3Bvt0JVr87UcOj69Kqw5R2Nmf4FWs03Hdx",
     "Issuer": "JWTAuthenticationServer",
     "Audience": "JWTServicePostmanClient",
     "Subject": "JWTServiceAccessToken"
   },


Register the JWT authentication service in Program.cs file:
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
 using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
 using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
 using System.Text;

 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

 // Add services to the container.

 builder.Services.AddControllers();
 // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
     options.SwaggerDoc("V1", new OpenApiInfo
     {
         Version = "V1",
         Title = "WebAPI",
         Description = "Product WebAPI"
     });
     options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
     {
         Scheme = "Bearer",
         BearerFormat = "JWT",
         In = ParameterLocation.Header,
         Name = "Authorization",
         Description = "Bearer Authentication with JWT Token",
         Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http
     });
     options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                 {
                     new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                         Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                             Id = "Bearer",
                                 Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                         }
                     },
                     new List < string > ()
                 }
             });
 });

 // Adding Authentication
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
     {
         options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     })
     // Adding Jwt Bearer
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
         options.SaveToken = true;
         options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
         {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
             ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
         };
         options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
         options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
         {
             OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
             {
                 var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                 logger.LogError("Authentication failed: {Exception}", context.Exception.ToString());
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             },
             OnChallenge = context =>
             {
                 var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                 logger.LogWarning("OnChallenge error: {0}", context.Error);
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             },
             OnMessageReceived = context =>
             {
                 var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                 var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                 {
                     logger.LogWarning("Token is null or empty");
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 }

                 // Log the raw token for debugging
                 logger.LogInformation("Token received: {Token}", token);

                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             }
         };
 });

 var app = builder.Build();

 // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
 if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
         options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json", "Product WebAPI");
     });
 }

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization(); 

 app.MapControllers();

 app.Run();


Add a UserInfo class to receive username and password.
 public class UserInfo
 {
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
 }


Add a TokenController controller to generate token:
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class TokenController : ControllerBase
 {
     public IConfiguration _configuration; 

     public TokenController(IConfiguration config )
     {
         _configuration = config; 
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Post(UserInfo _userData)
     {
         if (_userData != null && _userData.Email != null && _userData.Password != null)
         { 
             if (_userData.Email =="aa@hotmail.com")
             {
                 //create claims details based on the user information
                 var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                     {
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _userData.Email),
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"),
                         new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                     };

                 var token = GetToken(authClaims);
                 return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
             }
             else
             {
                 return BadRequest("Invalid credentials");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             return BadRequest();
         }
     }

     private JwtSecurityToken GetToken(List<Claim> authClaims)
     {
         var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
         var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

         var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
             issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
             audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
             expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
             claims: authClaims,
             signingCredentials: credentials
             );

         return token;
     }
 }


In the API controller, add Authorize attribute:
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 [Authorize]
 public class TodoController : ControllerBase
 {
     // GET: api/<TodoController>
     [HttpGet]
     public IEnumerable<string> Get()
     {
         return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
     }



The test result as below:
Without token, it will show 401 error:

Call the token controller to get the token (copy the token from response body):

Click the lock icon:

Add token to swagger:

Then execute the data controller again, we can see the JWT token already add on the header, and we can get the data success.


Got same issue on .net 8.0. Downgrade Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization to 8.0.11

after downgrade the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization to 8.0.11, the issue has disappeared? In my sample, I'm using the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.12.3 and create a new API application using the API template and there is no need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization package specially. So, can you tell us the detail steps to reproduce the problem?
